# element selection with prototype js

Tags: javascript, regex, dom, prototypejs

I'm having a some problems with a page where I have an input to take product EAN code and compare that to a table listing of products and update the input box with id `ean_xxxx` to `oldValue+1`.  My current code looks like this:

```
function updateProductQty(ean) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].id == "ean_" + ean)
        {
            inputs[i].value = Number(inputs[i].value) + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

That I call with this code on the input for EAN-code `onchange="updateProductQty(this.value);"`

Now the problem is that the input box with ID `ean_xxxxx` is located inside a table row, and I also need to compare to a value in a previous TD-tag.  The value I'm looking for is surrounded by HTML like this:

```
<td>
    <h5 class="title">....</h5>
    <div><strong>...</strong> A252502</div>
    <dl class="item-options">
        <dt>...</dt>
        <dd>..</dd>
    </dl>
</td>
.... more <td>-tags
<td> ... <input id="ean_xxxx" .... /> ... </td>
```

As you can see, when I locate the input tag, I never know which row in the table I'm at, and the value I want to add a check for is "A252502".

The site uses Prototype as js framework, which I have no experience in what so ever, so I mostly use basic JS where Google fails me for Prototype solutions.

If only I could get the TD contents, I could strip the -tag and any spaces to get the value - but how can search for it?  I can't even step back in the DOM tree, because I either get the EAN code or this internal article ID, not both. So no `inputs[i]` to start out from.  Any help is highly appreciated, no matter if it's in Prototype syntax or basic JS.

Comment: Yes, you really should use an [id selector](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar/index.html) for that input

Comment: What I'm looking for is `A252502` from the html `<div><strong>...</strong> A252502</div>` inside that <td> - and there's no way I can change the HTML output, I have to use JS.

Comment: "A252502" is not even an element, so selecting it is tricky. You could try something like `document.getElementById('ean_'+ean).parentNode.parentNode.firstElementChild.querySelector("div strong").nextSibling` (not sure of the prototype equivalent)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. My existing code for getting the input tag. I tried just using an id selector, but prototype drives me crazy - I must have had some good reason for not using it. Perhaps I gave up with getting the syntax right.

Comment: I can't traverse from the EAN input, since it's either EAN or the article number I get as input not both. But I'm much closer now. Cleaned up my existing code and have found the right DIV so my output now is `<strong>...</strong> A252502`.  Now to find some method to get like last word or split by space maybe...

Comment: try to run `"<strong>...</strong> A252502".stripTags()` which will strip any html from a string.

Comment: You can get the last `TextNode` from the div, or you can use [regex match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) or [string split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on the `textContent`/`innerText` (or `innerHTML` if needed)

Comment: @GeekNum88: there is no `stripTags()` string method in JavaScript

Comment: Thats a PrototypeJS function, but it only removes the tags, not the content. Nevermind, I have solved it already.

Comment: @Bergi but there is in PrototypeJS http://api.prototypejs.org/language/String/prototype/stripTags/ which is what the question is tagged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it. Here's how:

```
function updateProductQty(ean) {
    var input = $("ean_" + ean);
    if (input) {
        input.value = Number(input.value) + 1;
    } else {
        var trs = $$('.order-tables tbody tr');
        for (var i = 0; i < trs.size(); i++) {
            if (trs[i].down('div')) {
                if (trs[i].down('div').innerHTML.split(" ")[1] == ean) {
                    trs[i].down('td').next(4).down('input').value = Number(trs[i].down('td').next(4).down('input').value) + 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do `input.value++;`